# Assignment Vs Parameterized constructor c++

Tags: c++, constructor

Which of the following method is better (used for class A or class B)?
Will compiler do optimization for class A and function foo1?

(When I asked this question to one of my colleague he talked about stack, which I didn't understood. can someone please explain it, or point me to a reference which explains it in details? )

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class A
{
public:
   A::A(){}
   A::~A(){}

   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

void foo1()
{
    A objA;
    objA.a = 1;
    objA.b = 2;
    objA.c = 3;
}

//
class B
{
public:
   B::B(int ia, int ib, int ic):a(ia), b(ib), c(ic){}
   B::~B(){}

   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

void foo2()
{
    B objB(1,2,3);
}
```

Comment: The results will likely depend upon the compiler. The only way to know is to benchmark both alternatives yourself.

Comment: After eliminating your compiler errors, it turns out [it doesn't matter](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67124532cbe58338). In general, measure, don't guess.

Comment: As a matter of practice write the cleanest working code possible _then_ profile and optimize as necessary. As another matter of practice member variables should be initialized in the ctor initializer list rather than the body of the constructor.